# Wygwam inside of a grid -- has_excerpt conditional not working

Tags: conditionals

I'm unable to test for the has_excerpt condition, when trying to display excerpt and extended content in a grid. In this example, "booklist" is a grid field and book is a wygwam field within that grid:

```
{booklist:book:excerpt}
{booklist:book:has_excerpt}
{booklist:book:extended}
```

This all works... it will print the excerpt, then the "y" then the extended content. However, if I try to test for has_excerpt, it breaks:

```
{if booklist:book:has_excerpt}
  {booklist:book:extended}
{/if}
```

This conditional doesn't work and in fact triggers a PHP error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: User Warning
Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if "<p>This massive unfinished modernist novel examines many issues that cannot be categorized.":has_excerpt}
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 2762
```

I've tried {if booklist:book:has_excerpt == "y"} and {if "{booklist:book:has_excerpt} == "y"} as well, and neither works. Just to confirm that it works outside of a grid, I tried this (where "book" is a wygwam field not in a grid)...

```
  {if book:has_excerpt}
    <p>{book:extended}</p>
  {/if}
```

And it works fine. Any ideas how to make that conditional 1. work and 2. not trigger a PHP error? Thanks in advance.

j.

Answer (score 0):

```
{if "{booklist:book:has_excerpt}"}
  Yup
{if:else}
  Nope
{/if}
```

Should work. Note how we've made the has_excerpt a string by using " ".

Your example of `{if "{booklist:book:has_excerpt} == "y"}` was almost right, but you didn't close the String after `has_excerpt`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the answer. However that was a typo in my comment when asking the question... NOT a typo in my actual code. In my actual code I had actually tried {if "{booklist:book:has_excerpt}" == "y"} but what happens is that it gives me a blank screen... if I do the same conditional with a wygwam field NOT inside of a grid, it works fine... i.e. {if "{book:has_excerpt}"} (where book is a wygwam field) works fine. However, INside of a grid, if I try {if "{booklist:book:has_excerpt}"} (where booklist is a grid and book is a wygwam field) it breaks the page and gives me a white page...

Comment: What versions of EE and Wygwam are you using?

Comment: EE 2.7.3
Wygwam 3.3.1

Comment: I tested it on EE 2.8.1 and Wygwam 3.3.1 and it worked as above. I can't see anything in the changelogs that suggest 2.8.x fixed this, but unfortunately I don't have a 2.7.3 site at hand to test it on. Is updating an option?

Comment: Those conditionals should work without quotes and braces as of v2.9+. Quoting and bracing is a workaround on older versions, but will break if a quote appears in that field's content.